# AngularJS and ModelForm: Submit button not working

Tags: angularjs, django, django-forms

The page is supposed to display the contents of the database in a table, with a "New" button to add a new entry to the db. When the user clicks the "New" button, a form appears below. It is a ModelForm for the user to input a new entry to the Model, and then submit via a "Submit" button below. This was working as expected, until I added in an AngularJS controller to handle the button click of "New". The problem is my "Submit" button does not work. I want it to submit the data to the ModelForm, but it appears to do nothing.

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <h2>Ratings</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Beer Name</th>
            <th>Beer Rating</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Brewer</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for rating in ratings %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ rating.beer_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ rating.score }}</td>
            <td>{{ rating.notes }}</td>
            <td>{{ rating.brewer }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'rating-edit' rating.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ rating.id }}" name="edit">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'rating-delete' rating.id  %}" value="{{ rating.id }}" name="delete" >Delete</a></td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <a ng-model="buttonClick" ng-click="is_clicked()" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>


          <div ng-show="buttonClick" ng-cloak>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                  <h2>Enter a new rating</h2>
                  <form role="form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p>Beer Name: <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.beer_name"></input></p>
                    <p>Score: <input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="myForm.score"></input></p>
                    <p>Notes: <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.notes"></input></p>
                    <p>Brewer: <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.brewer"></input></p>
                    <p><button ng-click="submit_to_form(myForm)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></p>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.myForm = {beer_name:'beer_name', score:'score', notes:'notes', brewer:'brewer'};
    $scope.buttonClick = false; 
    $scope.is_clicked = function() {
      $scope.buttonClick=true;
      console.log($scope.buttonClick)
    }
    $scope.submit_to_form = function(data) {
      $http.post('rating-home', data);
    }
  })
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

And urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from ratings.views import home, RatingCreate, delete, edit

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-home'),
    url(r'rating/add/$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-add'),
    url(r'rating/delete/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', delete , name='rating-delete'),
    url(r'rating/edit/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', edit , name='rating-edit'),
]
```

And views.py for the Submit button:

```
class RatingCreate(View):
    """ Create a new Rating """
    form_class = RatingForm
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        context = {'ratings': Rating.objects.all(), 'form': form}
        #return render(request, 'home.html', context)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _ = form.save()
            return redirect('rating-home')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form: form'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should handle submitting the form with angular

```
<form ng-submit="myFunc(myData)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myData.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myData.phone">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**OR**

```
<form >
    <input type="text" ng-model="myData.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myData.phone">
    <button ng-click="myFunc(myData)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**and your controller:**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myData= {name:'' , phone:''};  
    $scope.myFunc = function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // data(myData array) can be send with angular $http.post() method 
      // e.g. : $http.post('/myUrl/', data)
    }
  })
```

**Update:**

[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm) is a good tutorial for angular $http service!

Comment: And then how does angular submit that info to the form? So how would myFunc() work?

Comment: So once I collect all of the fields, how do I bundle them back up into a form in myFunc()?

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my code, but I think I'm still missing something.

Comment: Ok I was a step behind. So now I've updated my code again. I'm getting an Syntax Error Unexpected token ":" on the $scope.myForm=... line.

Comment: you should inject `$http` service to your controller `function($scope, $http)`

Comment: I'm confused about how, in your example, you can use myData as an object with fields (myData.name, myData.phone). I don't see a ng-model="myData" anywhere. Do you have to declare it?

Comment: let me test my example

Comment: was my mistake!  try :  `$scope.myData={name:'' , phone:''};`  as an object

Comment: Thanks, that's better now. But it's still not posting the form. I'm not doing this right.

Comment: you're welcome.  try to follow tutorial's examples . . .